# Linear Regression, Standard Error Issue

Tags: java, math, apache-commons

Ok, I have a list of doubles which I first want to use as data for regression and then compare an observation with the respective estimate value (standard error).

But, when I use [SimpleRegression](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html) it just records 2 parameters (I'm guessing the first and the last), so when I try to check for the standard error I get a OutOfRangeException.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using something else than SimpleRegression? It seems strange that it doesn't store every (x,y) pair of estimates in the RegressionResults variable.

Here's my code

```
//Linear Least Squares method
    SimpleRegression regression = new SimpleRegression();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        regression.addData(i, list.get(i));
    }
    //I want to see how much a certain max differs from its estimate value.
    int indexOfTop = list.indexOf(secondTop);
    RegressionResults results = regression.regress();

    //How much this calculated top differ from the regression line

    double errorOfEstimate = 0;
    try {
        System.out
                .println("Parameters: " + results.getNumberOfParameters());
        errorOfEstimate = results.getStdErrorOfEstimate(indexOfTop);
    } catch (OutOfRangeException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> But, when I use SimpleRegression it just records 2 parameters (I'm
>   guessing the first and the last), so when I try to check for the
>   standard error I get a OutOfRangeException.

You are estimating only two parameters, X and Y for simple regression, if you want to see how many samples you have added check `getN()` method http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/RegressionResults.html#getN()

> What am I doing wrong? Should I be using something else than
>   SimpleRegression? It seems strange that it doesn't store every (x,y)
>   pair of estimates in the RegressionResults variable.

I think you want to get the prediction and compare with your observation, something which is explained here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.4_Simple_regression

Comment: Do you know what I can use to have more than two parameters as estimations then? I want a point of estimation for every point of observation I've added basically.

Edit: Scratch that, I'm a fool. Obviously I can use the linear function, just adding the x-value...Slope*x + intercept! Thanks for the help!